# React-Hook-Form validate error message doesn't work with Register with group input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

thank you for reading my problem.

I'm new into React and React Hook Form.
I've a problem with validation error message with input with Register with data in data object.

Example:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="firstname"
  placeholder="First Name"
  className="input input-bordered input-sm w-full max-w-xs"
  {...register("name.first_name")}
  aria-invalid={errors.first_name ? "true" : "false"}
/>
{
  errors.first_name?.type === "required" && (
    <p className="text-red-500 text-xs" role="alert">
      * First name is required
    </p>
  );
}
```

I succeed display the error message, but when I change the Register into two values (data Name with First Name, etc) it doesn't display the error.

[I would like to create a form with data like this, ex: First Name under Name, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfKfN.png)

I tried to search React Hook Form Documentation but the example all with single Register format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, you may have data that is grouped into an object, like a name that has a first name and a last name. In this case, you can use a dot (.) to connect the object name and the property name when you register your input fields. This way, `react-hook-form` will know how to store and validate your data.

For example:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="name.first_name"
  placeholder="First Name"
  className="input input-bordered input-sm w-full max-w-xs"
  {...register("name.first_name", { required: true })}
  aria-invalid={errors.name?.first_name ? "true" : "false"}
/>;
{
  errors.name?.first_name?.type === "required" && (
    <p className="text-red-500 text-xs" role="alert">
      * First name is required
    </p>
  );
}

<input
  type="text"
  name="name.last_name"
  placeholder="Last Name"
  className="input input-bordered input-sm w-full max-w-xs"
  {...register("name.last_name", { required: true })}
  aria-invalid={errors.name?.last_name ? "true" : "false"}
/>;
{
  errors.name?.last_name?.type === "required" && (
    <p className="text-red-500 text-xs" role="alert">
      * Last name is required
    </p>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for respone.
Yes I have succeed pass this object and property, but the problem is in the validation.
`errors.name?.last_name?.type` read the Register field `(last_name)`, but when I have dot(.) to separate object name `(name.last_name)`, the error message did not appear/called.

I'm confused with that

Comment: Hi, which version of `react-hook-form` are you using?

Comment: what's wrong? please see https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-feather-8zdzjr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you, it's working now.
I just missed some characters there lol, thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes of course this is the answer, sorry I forgot to click the tick.